# how to paste data from R to stackoverflow?

Tags: support

I can paste code from my R script to Stack Overflow but I struggle with posting a subset of my data using subset() or head(). The best I can do is use dput(head(mydata,4)) but I would like my data to appear in columns as in a dataframe. I have seen the link below but are there other ways to post data from R to Stack Overflow?

[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 5):

You should post the printed output of `head(mydata)` to show, visually, what your data look like (if that's helpful for understanding your problem, which is not always the case). But, then, also include a `dput(mydata)` so that everyone can quickly reproduce your data.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `dput()` sometimes clutter the post with too much irrelevant information, and forces whoever is trying to answer your question to copy and paste it in R, in order to visualize your data. I vote against it. To keep both good appearance and immediate reproducibility, I suggest this:

For dataframes: post a minimal subset of your data; minimal in the sense that it reproduces the error you get or exemplifies the result you want. Example:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Id   Color
  01    blue
  02    cyan
  03     red
  04   black
")
```

For matrices and vectors: Create minimal fake data, in the sense described above. Example:

```
x <- runif(100)
y <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
```

More complex objects: post the code that creates them.

I believe that this helps your question to get more answer, better answers, and quick answers. :-)